# Electrodynamics modelled by U(1) gauge theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

As the article ['Electrodynamics in general spacetime'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446463/electrodynamics-in-general-spacetime) greatly explains, the U(1)-gauge theory is a good base for working in non-simply connected spaces. But I wonder whether there is a deep reason to relate electrodynamics and complex line bundles and connections (anything to do with quantum theory, perhaps?). I know Yang-Mills theory has to do with all this idea of studying bundles and connections, but I hope it has physical meaning and not just 'geometrical convenience'. Can anyone explain me intuitively this mathematics-physics interplay?

More concisely, suppose our ‘electromagnetic world’ is modelled by means of a complex line bundle with base the 4-dimensional spacetime.

-In Quantum Mechanics, a complex valued function over spacetime should be understood as a ‘phased’-distribution of the probability of a particle being in a certain place. How should be understood a section over our complex line bundle?

-And in this setting, which is the role of a connection?

As it may be difficult to answer this in a few words, it would be also helpful if somebody pointed out some small fragment of a book where this questions are studied. All ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_gauge_theory ?

Comment: Thank you, I have just read it. But the problem is still there: which is the intimate relation between Electrodynamics and U(1)?

Comment: Can you point to a case when you have a satisfactory (for you) answer to a similar question? Why is mechanics linked to ODE's and symplectic geometry?

Comment: For example, if somebody asked me "Why are particles described as complex-valued functions in Quantum Mechanics?" then I would answer "Because experiments have shown that particles should not be thought as points, but behave like having a certain probability distribution over space, which moreover has been proven to interact like waves, i.e. having constructive and destructive phenomena, and therefore it seems as there is a phase information  encoded in the particle together to the probability amplitude".

Comment: Or if somebody asked "And why to use spinorial bundles when describing electrons?" the I would answer "Well, particles behave like waves, i.e. functions, but if I accept there is some spin 'vector', it becomes alltogether a 'vector-valued function', whose behaviour is suitably described by means of this spinorial bundle".

Comment: @Jjm, from your own "sample answers", it seems that your question is not really about mathematical intuition but physical intuition. As such, it might be a better fit for [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). One thing you should keep in mind, though, is that the U(1) of quantum mechanics and the U(1) of electromagnetism have different origins, so similarities between them are more of a coincidence than not. The U(1) in EM appears even classically, when considering the differences between the field-strength and the vector-potential.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: I'm not sure that the U(1) appears classically if you just look at the electromagnetic field alone.  Classical gauge transformations in Minkowski spacetime, say, are simply $A \mapsto A + d\Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a real function.  There is no indication here that $A$ is a connection on a circle bundle, as opposed to an $\mathbb{R}$ bundle.  It's only when you couple electromagnetism to matter that the gauge invariance of the classical action will tell you that the matter is in a unitary representation of the gauge group and, being finite-dimensional, this picks out U(1)...

Comment: (cont'd) I do agree that the two U(1)s are different, though: the classical one and the quantum phase.

Comment: Isn't this question (minus the references to quantum theory) about how the classical Maxwell equations can be reformulated as the self-dual equations for a $U(1)$-connection on the trivial complex line bundle over Minkowski space? I don't remember where I learned this, but perhaps someone could provide a reference?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill, you are right of course about the ambiguity between $A$ being a connection on a U(1)-bundle or an $\mathbb{R}$-bundle. The point I wanted to make is that the U(1) of EM appears because of the change from $F$ to $A$, because the identity $F=dA$ may not always be solved for $A$ globally, unless it is interpreted as the connection form on a bundle, rather than a simple $1$-form, despite ambiguity about the bundle itself being of U(1) or $\mathbb{R}$ type. This particular issue appears already at the classical level.

Comment: For a specific reference, one can look at this recent paper by [Benini, Dappiaggi and Schenkel](http://arXiv.org/abs/1303.2515). Of course, the basic material is classic and has been treated in many places, one of which is the book [Gauge Fields, Knots, Gravity](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=9810217293) by Baez and Muniain.

Comment: For (concerning the fibre bundle issue not yet sufficient) answers see this crosspost on PhysicsOverflow http://www.physicsoverflow.org/25187/intuition-behind-model-electrodynamics-general-spacetime.